# Не получается сделать внутреннюю тень в тексте

Tags: html, css, color

Я столкнулся с проблемой при создании внутренней тени для текста. Я пробовал этот способ (некоторый css почему-то не работает в таких онлайн-компиляторах, но код виден):

```css
.text {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -moz-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Text
</div>
```

В результате получается светло-серый текст, но мне нужен такст другого цвета. Когда я попробовал изменить цвет текста и цвет тени (не альфу), стало видно что]6 судя по всему, "background-clip: text;" не обрезает область текста, и я вижу размытый силуэт за пределами контуров букв.

Вот что получается (здесь видимо перепутаны местами цвета для текста и тени, но виден нахлест):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 А вот что нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Размер текста маленький, может поэтому тень сильно рассеивается, попробуйте уменьшить размер тени или увеличить размер текста, если конечно я вас правильно понял...

```css
.text {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -moz-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}

.text2 {
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -moz-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Text
</div>

<div class="text2">
Text
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но изменение размера текста не помагает, уменьшение размера тени делает нахлест тени за контур текста менее заметным, но он должен отсутствовать совсем, почему он не обрезается с помощью background-clip: text ?..

Comment: Метод изложен здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/154211/  я пробовал и с <h1> и со <span>

Comment: Что бы работал этот метод обязательно  должен быть однотонный фон который будет сливаться с цветом тени. Вот пример http://codepen.io/L2Banners/pen/AXzyWY тень существует но она сливается с фоном и создается эффект внутренней тени так как цвет у текста прозрачный.

Answer (score 1):

***100%-ый вариант***, работающий во всех браузерах, попробуй:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
/* CHANGE ME TO ANY COLOR TO EXPERIMENT */
body {
  background: #ffcccc;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 75px 0;
}

.stripes-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  -moz-background-size: 4px 4px;
  -o-background-size: 4px 4px;
  -webkit-background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(77, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.brand {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

/* the magic */
.inner-shadow {
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 4px #ffe6e6, 0px 0px 0px black, 0px 0px 2px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes-overlay"></div>

<div class="content">
  <h1 class="inner-shadow brand">Inner Shadow</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?